# Size of int array C++

Tags: c++, string, integer

I'm trying to allocate a new array if integers (See HwGrades allocation below)
When I put the HwNum=2, the new function creates an array of size 1 only!
and when the for loop iterates 2 times it doesnt give me access violation
Help would be appreciated..

Here's the constructor

```
EE_Course::EE_Course(int Course_ID, char * Course_Name, int Hw_Num, double Hw_Weigh,int Factor_)
    {
        CourseID = Course_ID;
        CourseName = new char[strlen(Course_Name) + 1];
        strcpy(CourseName, Course_Name);
        HwNum = Hw_Num;
        HwWeigh = Hw_Weigh;
        HwGrades = new int [HwNum];  // STARTING FROM HERE
        for (int i = 0; i < Hw_Num; i++) { //UNTIL HERE
            HwGrades[i] = 0;
        }
    Factor_ = 0;
    ExamGrade = 0;

}
```

And those are the Course class private variables :

```
protected:
    int CourseID;
    int HwNum;
    char* CourseName;
    double HwWeigh;
    int ExamGrade;
    int* HwGrades;

};
```

Comment: how do you know the size is 1?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use std::vector? That will simplify things.

Comment: @seleciii44 from the Watch window

Comment: As a point of style: once you assign to `HwNum`, you should only use that instead of alternating back to `Hw_Num`.

Comment: knew it! it doesn't show all of it. It just shows the address of first element. That's why you only see one. If it was a an array (not a pointer) you could see all the elements.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. Not proper modern C++, but it does look OK. If you're seeing "size 1" from the debugger then you might be doing something wrong with the debugger.

Comment: I can't see an obvious problem in those fragments. Can you provide a minimal complete verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Another style comment: This is a constructor but you are setting values in the constructor body that should be set by constructor member initialization instead. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: Side note: You should change your variable naming convention (you confuse yourself with `HwNum` and `Hw_Num`)

Comment: Yes.. I changed the real code! I only wanted an answer for that part which was answered by @seleciii44!
I used member Initializatio and changed the member variables to HwNum_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The debugger does not show the whole array if it is a pointer. It shows the address of the array and the first element the array is pointing. So there is nothing wrong with your code.

You could see it if it was defined as an array:

```
int HwGrades[100];
```

If you really want to use a pointer and see it's content, you have two choices:

1. Define it as an array, debug it, fix/verify your code and turn back to pointer.
2. I don't know what is you environment, but usually there is a memory view option. You can check what's in the array any time you want. Just open the memory view of your IDE and watch the address of your pointer.

**EDIT**:

Apparently there is a third(and the best) option. See [Rabbi Shuki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34598793/1632887).

Answer (score 5):

The debugger just shows one element. Here's why:

The type of `HwGrades` is `int*`. So when showing the contents of `HwGrades` what should the debugger do? The debugger does not know, that the pointer is actually pointing to the first element of an array. It assumes it just points to an `int`. Therefore, the debugger shows just the first element of the array that is actually of size 2.

If you're using the Visual Studio debugger, you can write `HwGrades,2` in the watch window to see the first two elements of the array. Replace `2` by whatever your tickles your fancy. ;)

However, generally I would strongly advice to use the STL container [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for dynamic arrays. It will be easier to program and the debugger will be your friend without the hassle.

Comment: Wow! I appreciate this  explaination.. Thank you.

Comment: @SijaanHallak Added a few tipps for you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the next cells of the array in the watch screen you can put the name and add a comma and the number of cells you want to see.

I.E.

```
HwGrades, 2
```

Comment: @SijaanHallak Good to hear. I would be thankfull if you could vote the answers that helped you, as i am pretty new to the site and need to build my reputation.